# How do I JSDoc Backbone Attributes/Options

Tags: backbone.js, jsdoc3

I am trying to determine the best way to use JSDoc 3 to document the attributes and options arguments to a `Backbone.Model`.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do:

```
/**
  * @class
  * @attribute {string} foo the foo attribute
  * @attribute {integer} bar the bar attribute
  * @option    {bolean} baz the baz option
  * @option    {string} qux the qux option
  */
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
});
```

However there is no `@option` tag in JSDoc 3, and `@attribute` doesn't mean the same thing as a Backbone attribute.  In theory I think one could somehow make custom tags like the ones in my pseudo-code, but I couldn't find any existing plug-in with these, and the documentation on how to create custom tags is almost non-existent.

So, since I seem stuck with the built-in tags for now, my question is: what's the next best thing to my pseudo-code (using actual JSDoc 3 tags)?

NOTE: There are several similar questions to this one ([How to jsdoc annotate BackboneJS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438800/how-to-jsdoc-annotate-backbonejs-code), [How do I document AMD + Backbone project with JSDoc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166343/how-do-i-document-amd-backbone-project-with-jsdoc3)) but they all focus on the "big picture" of getting Backbone objects recognized at all.  I couldn't find any that specifically addressed the issue of attributes/options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer myself in this (non-Backbone-specific) Stack Overflow thread: [How to describe "object" arguments in jsdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460604/how-to-describe-object-arguments-in-jsdoc).

To summarize, you can document attributes/options by making an initial parameter (eg. `@param attributes`), then making a `@param attributes.foo` or `@param options.bar` tag.  In other words, my pseudo code could be re-done properly with the following syntax:

```
/**
  * @class
  * @param {Object} attributes
  * @param {string} attributes.foo the foo attribute
  * @param {integer} attributes.bar the bar attribute
  * @param {Object} options
  * @param {boolean} options.baz the baz option
  * @param {string} options.qux the qux option
  */
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
});
```

I still think that it'd be preferable if there was some sort of JSDoc3-Backbone plug-in that allowed `@attribute`/`@option` tags, so if one exists and someone posts it as an answer I'll gladly accept that answer instead of my own.